# Generating functions for $\log^3(1-x)$ of $\log^3(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to find generating functions which will give me a power logarithm.

I am trying to find generating sums in the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\,x^n = -\frac{\log^2(1-x)}{1-x}$$

or

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\,x^n = \frac{\log^2(x)}{x}.$$

Something, which will return $\log^3$ in the end.

Help is required!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have:
$$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$, hence:
$$-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 1}H_n x^n.$$
and since $\frac{d}{dx}\log^2(1-x) = -2\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}$ we have:
$$\log^2(1-x) = 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}\tag{1}.$$
Since, by partial summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}= H_N^2-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_n}{n+1} = H_N^2-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac{H_N^2+H_N^{(2)}}{2}, \quad \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}=\frac{H_N^2-H_N^{(2)}}{2}$$
so:

> $$\frac{\log^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 1}(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})\,x^{n}\tag{2}$$

and:

> $$\log^3(1-x)=-3\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n+1}\,x^{n+1}\tag{3}$$

for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$.

Comment: I recall that $$H_n\triangleq\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k},\qquad H_n^{(2)}\triangleq\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Comment: Where did you get the partial summation formula for $H_n/n$?

Comment: @Amad27: partial summation is a standard technique - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts . Here, we just apply it to : $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}1\cdot H_n = N H_N - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n(H_{n+1}-H_n),$$ then to $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\cdot H_n.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Extension to general powers $(-\log (1-x))^n$**

Exploiting the powerful idea of paramteric differentiation exposed here by Felix Marin I was able to find expressions for arbitrary powers $n$ and provide examples for $n = 1..8$.

The results for $n\ge 4$ seem to be new (please correct me if not).

The derivation of the general term is a nice excise in special functions and combinatorics which I shall present later.

**Results**

Let $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ be a natural number and define a series expansion as follows

$$\frac{1}{n}(-\log (1-x))^n=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^k}{k} a(n,k)\tag{1}$$

Then the coefficients for the first few $n$ are in the format $\{n,a(n,k)\}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{1,1\} \\
 \left\{2,H_{k-1}\right\} \\
 \left\{3,\left(H_{k-1}\right){}^2-H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right\} \\
 \left\{4,\left(H_{k-1}\right){}^3-3 H_{k-1}^{(2)} H_{k-1}+2 H_{k-1}^{(3)}\right\} \\
 \left\{5,\left(H_{k-1}\right){}^4-6 H_{k-1}^{(2)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^2+8 H_{k-1}^{(3)} H_{k-1}+3 \left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^2-6 H_{k-1}^{(4)}\right\} \\
 \left\{6,\left(H_{k-1}\right){}^5-10 H_{k-1}^{(2)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^3+20 H_{k-1}^{(3)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^2+15 \left(\left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^2-2 H_{k-1}^{(4)}\right) H_{k-1}-20 H_{k-1}^{(2)} H_{k-1}^{(3)}+24 H_{k-1}^{(5)}\right\} \\
 \left\{7,\left(H_{k-1}\right){}^6-15 H_{k-1}^{(2)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^4+40 H_{k-1}^{(3)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^3+45 \left(\left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^2-2 H_{k-1}^{(4)}\right) \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^2-24 \left(5 H_{k-1}^{(2)} H_{k-1}^{(3)}-6 H_{k-1}^{(5)}\right) H_{k-1}+5 \left(-3 \left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^3+18 H_{k-1}^{(4)} H_{k-1}^{(2)}+8 \left(\left(H_{k-1}^{(3)}\right){}^2-3 H_{k-1}^{(6)}\right)\right)\right\} \\
 \left\{8,\left(H_{k-1}\right){}^7-21 H_{k-1}^{(2)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^5+70 H_{k-1}^{(3)} \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^4+105 \left(\left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^2-2 H_{k-1}^{(4)}\right) \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^3-84 \left(5 H_{k-1}^{(2)} H_{k-1}^{(3)}-6 H_{k-1}^{(5)}\right) \left(H_{k-1}\right){}^2-35 \left(3 \left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^3-18 H_{k-1}^{(4)} H_{k-1}^{(2)}-8 \left(H_{k-1}^{(3)}\right){}^2+24 H_{k-1}^{(6)}\right) H_{k-1}+6 \left(35 H_{k-1}^{(3)} \left(H_{k-1}^{(2)}\right){}^2-84 H_{k-1}^{(5)} H_{k-1}^{(2)}-70 H_{k-1}^{(3)} H_{k-1}^{(4)}+120 H_{k-1}^{(7)}\right)\right\} \\
\end{array}
\right)\tag{2}$$

**Discussion**

By differentiating (1) with respect to $x$ we immediately obtain the interesting expansions

$$\frac{(-\log (1-x))^n}{1-x}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } x^k a(n,k+1)\tag{3}$$

This expansion is closely related to generating functions for various harmonic numbers.

EDIT 26.11.17

A direct approach would be multiplication of power series.

From

$$(-\log (1-x))^n=\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^k}{k}\right){}^n$$

and comparision with $(1)$ we conclude that

$$a(n,m)=\frac{m}{n} \sum _{m=\sum _{}k_{i}\\k_{i}\ge 1} \frac{1}{\prod _{i=1}^n k_{i}}$$

**Derivation**

Ready on paper. To be typed in here.

I shall wait a while, however, in case others wish to attempt the derivation.

Comment: @Felix Marin you might wish to see my generalization here. I point this out in a comment because the OP is already three years old.

Comment: @Przemo  I appreciate your various contributions to harmonic number questions here. You might be interested in my answer here on the power expansion of the general power of $\log (1-x)$ .

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\verts{x}\ <\ 1}$:

> \begin{align}
> \pars{1 - x}^{\mu}&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\mu \choose n}x^{n}\quad\imp\quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
> \pars{1 - x}^{\mu}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x}
> &=&\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\partiald[2]{{\mu \choose n}}{\mu}\,x^{n}
> \\
> \pars{1 - x}^{\mu}\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x}
> &=&\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\partiald[3]{{\mu \choose n}}{\mu}\,x^{n}
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

It leads to:
\begin{align}
{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over 1 - x}
&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1}\partiald[2]{{\mu \choose n}}{\mu}}x^{n}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\color{#00f}{\pars{-1}^{n}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}
\partiald[2]{{\mu + n\choose n}}{\mu}}}x^{n}
\\[5mm]
\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x}
&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\dsc{\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald[3]{{\mu \choose n}}{\mu}}}x^{n}
\end{align}

> Limits can be expressed in terms of ${\sf Gamma}$ and ${\sf PolyGammas}$ functions.